# Cakephp - save method creating record but without data

Tags: cakephp

For some reason, my model's save method is creating records in the database but the fields are all empty or zeroes.

The form should allow for creating multiple records with a single form submission.

My $this->data array:

```
Array
(
[OfferingStudent] => Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [offering_id] => 35
            [owing] => 209.00
            [student_id] => 31
        )

)

)
```

Using the save method: $this->Students->OfferingsStudent->saveAll($this->data)

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe when using `saveAll` you don't actually include the name of the model in the array. Try changing your data to just this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [offering_id] => 35
            [owing] => 209.00
            [student_id] => 31
        )

)
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data

from that page:

> Note that we are passing $data['Article'] instead of usual $data. When
>   saving multiple records of same model the records arrays should be
>   just numerically indexed without the model key.

or rather, just use `$this->data->OfferingStudent` as the first argument to saveAll instead of just `$this->data`